# When should I use this->functionname() over classname::functionname() for calling member functions?

Tags: c++, oop, namespaces, this

I've been looking over some example code which uses both `this->functionname()` and `classname::functionname()` to call functions in the same class.

Is there actually a difference between these two methods?

Also, is there a difference between these methods and just simply calling the function using **`functionname()`**?

Thanks.

Comment: Answer to this question is good candidate for this new Documentation thingy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual in C++, thing's are less simple than you might think.

There are three ways to call member functions.

1. just call the function: `foo();`
2. call with `this`: `this->foo();`
3. use the class's name: `classname::f();`

Numbers #1 and #2 are equivalent, some people prefer #2 because it's clearer that this is a member function and not a global function (these people are in a minority).

Whether #3 differs from #1 and #2 depends on whether the function called is a virtual function. If it's non-virtual there is no difference. If it *is* virtual **and** there's a more derived override of this function then #1 and #2 will called the derived function and #3 will call the override that exists in this class (or if there is no override in this class, the closest super-class).

The exception to the previous paragraph is when the call-site is in a constructor or a destructor. In this case, even if the function is virtual #1 and #2 will behave the same as #3 (call the override in this, or the closest super-class).

In addition if the function is `static` then #2 is invalid and #1 and #3 are equivalent when called from within the class but #3 is needed when called from outside the class.

<strike>I hope I didn't miss anything :)</strike>

**Things I missed:**

- `this` may be needed if the function is hidden by a global re-declared inside the calling function. See [@Dutow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38563685/3848).
- `this` can be useful when dealing with [two phase lookup](http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html?m=1) (when templates are involved). Thanks to [@Alejandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1274223/alejandro) for his comment.
- I'm guessing that using `using` may throw some more mud in the water but I can't be bothered to look into it at the moment (caveat emptor).

Indeed, not as simple as one might think...

Comment: You could also make the argument that `this` is also needed for proper [two phase lookup](http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html?m=1) in certain cases

Answer (score 3):

Usually? They are the same. But depending on the context, they might mean different things.

For example, consider the following extreme example (don't do this in a real project!):

```
void f() { std::cout << "f" << std::endl; }

class Cl {
public:
    void f() { std::cout << "Cl::f" << std::endl;  }
    void g() { 
        struct Cl {
            static void f() { std::cout << "inside Cl::f" << std::endl; }
        };
        void f();  

        f(); 
        Cl::f();
        this->f();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Cl a;
    a.g();

    return 0;

}
```

In this, the declaration of the global `f` shadows the member method `f`, resulting in the program outputting `f` instead of `Cl::f`.

The local `struct Cl` also shadows it's own typename, resulting in `Cl::f()` calling it's static `f` method.

Only calling `this->f()` explicitly results in calling `Cl::f`.

The variant with the typename is also commonly used when you want to call methods in the parent class when using inheritance and overriding virtual methods - but that's technically not the same class.

Comment: TIL that you can declare a function inside a function (and I thought that my answer was exhaustive...)

Comment: You sir, are evil! Well done (I've referenced your answer in mine).

Answer (score 1):

I think one reason to use this is in this scenario. E.g.

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo() { this->doFoo(); } //equivalent to just doFoo();
    void foo2() { Abstract::doFoo(); }
private:
    virtual void doFoo() { /* do stuff */ }
};
```

In the snippet when calling `foo` it will invoke `doFoo` in the most derived class. When calling `foo2` it will always call base implementation even if it was overriden.